# How to limit memory/item size in a named cache in windows app fabric cache?

Tags: caching, appfabric, appfabric-cache

I am relatively new to .net  / windows technologies and I need to use appfabric cache for a project.

After spending some time, I feel that one of the basic functionalities of a cache framework, namely limiting the size of a cache, is absent in the appfabric caching framework. I know that popular java caching frameworks like ehcache and hazelcast has this functionality through xml configuration elements (maxElementsInMemory attribute in ehcache , max-size attribute in hazelcast).

I know that this question has been asked previously in a similar form:

[How to set Windows Server AppFabric named cache size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13182648/how-to-set-windows-server-appfabric-named-cache-size)

However, I could not find a conclusive proposal to limit cache size per named cache basis in app fabric.

I need to expose caching apis to several application development groups. Each group is supposed to be assigned their own named cache but I need a mechanism to prevent cache abuse. Each cache user should live with their own limited named cache space. I.e they should not consume more memory than the amount reserved for them.

I do not want to write ugly custom code in my api to limit this and I believe that this is a basic requirement that a caching framework should support.

Any proposal for how to achieve this in app fabric will highly be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You might think AppFabric **should** support this, but the answer to the question you link to definitively states that it doesn't.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set Windows Server AppFabric named cache size?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13182648/how-to-set-windows-server-appfabric-named-cache-size)

Comment: I just wanted a solution proposal for my need. It would be much more helpful to offer a proposal instead of just saying that "this is not supported"...